# Extracting articles from Wiki Dump

Tags: java, xml, mediawiki, wiki, wikipedia

I have a huge wiki dump (~ 50GB after extracting the tar.bz file), from which I want to extract the individual articles. I am using the [wikixmlj](https://code.google.com/p/wikixmlj/) library to extract the contents and it does gives the title, text, categories mentioned at the end and a few other attributes. But I am more interested in the external links/references associated with each article, for which this library doesnt provide any API for.

Is there any elegant and efficient way to extract that other than parsing the `wikiText` that we get with the `getWikiText()` API.
Or is there any other java library to extract from this dump file, which gives me the title, content, categories and the references/external-links.

Comment: JWPL being probably the best. try these http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers

Comment: @Amit G JWPL requires me to store the dump contents in a SQL db. Is there any library that runs on the wiki dump file itself (.tar.bz2 or .tar)

Comment: No easy way out here. You will have write your own parser for wikitext. use javaRegEx or Antlr here.

Comment: Why not ask all of that from the API? If you need dumps, you can get 1) parsed content and references from a ZIM dump (kiwix.org), 2) titles, categories and external links from the SQL or txt.gz dumps of the respective tables (dumps.wikimedia.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML dump contains exactly what the library is offering you: the page text along with some basic metadata. It doesn't contain any metadata about categories or external links.

The way I see it, you have three options:

1. Use the specific SQL dumps for the data you need, e.g. categorylinks.sql for categories or externallinks.sql for external links. But there is no dump for references (because MediaWiki doesn't track those).
2. Parse the wikitext from the XML dump. This would have problems with templates.
3. Use your own instance of MediaWiki to parse the wikitext into HTML and then parse that. This could potentially handle templates too.

Comment: The actual XML file (after extraction), has every information, including references and external links. However, when I used the `wikixmlj` library, the API `getWikiText()` gave me only the content, after stripping off the links and references. Since I was solely interested in these links, I wrote a simple line-by-line parser to get each `<page></page>` tag and explicitly look for the references and external links.

Side note: `WikiXMLJ` provides categories available at the end of each wiki page

Answer (score 0):

May be too late but this link could help: http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~gabr/resources/code/wikiprep/wikiprep.html

Here is an example output of above program: http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~gabr/resources/code/wikiprep/sample.hgw.xml